# o que significa o "string" no CSS?

Tags: css, css3

Olá gostaria de saber exatamente o que significa o termo string no CSS e de que maneira ele é usado o CSS?

Comment: Em qualquer linguagem, uma string é um texto (pelo menos nunca ouvi falar de uma que tivesse um significado diferente), geralmente delimitado por `'` ou `"`. Se quer um exemplo: `background: url('caminho/minha imagem.png');` ou `content: ' uma string'`

Comment: olá @GuilhermeCostamilam então pelo que eu entendi  string é a palavra que fika entre as " aspas"  'tô certo ? '

Comment: Sim, pelo menos na maioria das linguagens. Algumas tem outras opções, por exemplo, no javascript `"Isso é uma string"`, `'isso também'` `\`e isso também\``, essa última permitindo interpolação

Comment: Essa é uma explicação simples, além de um texto, uma String é tipo de variável, que na verdade é uma classe. Mas isso não se aplica no CSS eu acredito

Comment: obrigado cara ! @GuilhermeCostamilam

Comment: O tipo de dados <string> é composto de qualquer número de caracteres cercados por aspas duplas ( " ) ou simples ( ' ).

Comment: Poderia [edit] e dar o contexto de onde viu o termo sendo usado? Seria melhor para garantir que as respostas se apliquem ao que originou de fato a dúvida.

Comment: @Bacco como vocÊ sugere ? sobre a  dição da pergunta ?

Comment: Talvez por um trecho e um link do tipo "Li no site tal (linkado para o site, se for o caso) essa frase: ......(insira aqui).... Nesse contexto, o que significa a expresão _string_?" -

Answer (score 1):

O tipo de dados CSS [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/string) representa uma sequência de caracteres. As cadeias de caracteres são usadas em várias propriedades CSS, como `content`, `font-family`, e `quotes`.

**Sintaxe:**

O tipo de dados  é composto de qualquer número de caracteres Unicode cercados por aspas duplas (") ou simples (').

**Exemplos:**

```
/ * Strings simples * /
"Esta string é marcada com aspas duplas."
'Esta cadeia é marcada por aspas simples.'

/ * Escapando caracteres * /
"Esta é uma string com \" uma aspa dupla com escape. "
"Esta string também tem \ 22 uma aspa dupla escapada."
'Esta é uma string com \' uma aspas simples com escape. '
'Esta cadeia também tem \ 27 uma cota simples de escape.'
"Esta é uma string com \\ uma barra invertida com escape."

/ * Nova linha em uma string * /
"Esta string tem uma quebra de \ Aline."

/ * String abrangendo duas linhas de código (essas duas seqüências terão saída idêntica) * /
"Um muito longo \
corda impressionante "
"Uma string realmente longa e impressionante"
```

Exemplo de uso com a propriedade `<content>`:

```
/* Valores <string> com caracteres especiais devem ser escritos */
/* com escape Unicode, por exemplo \00A0 para &nbsp; */
content: "prefixo";

/* Valores <url> */
content: url("http://www.example.com/test.png");
```

A propriedade CSS [content](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/content) é usada com os pseudoelementos ::before e ::after para gerar conteúdo em um elemento. Objetos inseridos usando a propriedade content são elementos substituídos anônimos.